# Calculate information within form view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= f.label :months, "Experience" %>
<%= f.hidden_field :months, :value => (params[:Years]*12) + params[:Months] %>
<%= number_field_tag "Years", nil, placeholder:"Years" %> Years <%= number_field_tag "Months", nil, placeholder:"Months" %> Months
```

As above;  I'd like to calculate and pass the information needed. Currently I error on the * method:

```
undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Well it's because your params[:Years] returns nil. There is no value for that parameter key. Can you guarantee that it will always be there? Maybe you should default it to 0 then. Something like `((params[:Years] || 0) * 12)` would do it.

Comment: Are you supposed to access params[:Years] in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the capitalize symbol `:Year` is the problem. Giving a new key for a hash it will return `nil`.

If there isn't `params[:year]` you should do the conversion with one of the cited: `#to_i`, `|| 0` or even else `Integer(value)`.

However, this kind of manipulation is safer done inside the controller method before rendering the view due easily `params` manipulation. You can set a variable in controller and then use it.

**Controller**

```
def action
  @months = (params[:years].to_i*12) + params[:months].to_i
end
```

**View**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :months, :value => @months %>
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1

params[:years] is nil, dooooh

you can test with

```
raise params[:Years].inspect
```

## 2

incompatible types, try:

```
:value => ((params[:Years].to_i * 12) + params[:Months].to_i)
```